# Understand the usage of timeout in beast::tcp_stream?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

Reference:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/timeouts.html
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__tcp_stream.html

```
    void on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec) return fail(ec, "resolve");
        // Set the timeout for the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
            results, beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep)
    {
        if(ec) return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        // beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never(); // Note: do NOT call this line for this question!!!

...
        host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());
        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/",
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_handshake, shared_from_this()));
    }
```

**Question 1**>
Will the timeout of beast::tcp_stream continue to work after a previous asynchronous operation finishes on time?

For example,
In above example, the timeout will expire after 30 seconds. If `async_connect` doesn't finish within 30 seconds, `session::on_connect` will receive an `error::timeout` as the value of `ec`. Let's assume the `async_connect` takes 10 seconds,
can I assume that `async_handshake` needs to finish within 20(i.e. 30-10) seconds otherwise a `error::timeout` will be sent to `session::on_handshake`? I infer to this idea based on the comments within `on_connect` function(i.e.

> Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream

). In other words, a timeout will only be turned off after it finishes the specified expiration period or is disabled by `expires_never`. Is my understanding correct?

**Question 2**> Also I want to know what a good pattern I should use for timeout in both `async_calling` and `async_callback` functions.

When we call an `async_calling` operation:

```
void func_async_calling()
{
  // set some timeout here(i.e. XXXX seconds)
  Step 1> beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(XXXX));
  Step 2> ws_.async_operation(..., func_async_callback, )
  Step 3> beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();
}
```

When we define a `async_callback` handle for an asynchronous operation:

```
void func_async_callback()
{
  Step 1>Either call 
    // Disable the timeout for the next logical operation.
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never(); 
  or
    // Enable a new timeout
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(YYYY));

  Step 2> call another asynchronous function
  Step 3> beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();
}
```

Does this make sense?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

Yes that's correct. The linked page has the confirmation:

```
// The timer is still running. If we don't want the next
// operation to time out 30 seconds relative to the previous
// call  to `expires_after`, we need to turn it off before
// starting another asynchronous operation.

stream.expires_never();
```

### Question 2

That looks fine. The only subtleties I can think of are

- often, because of [Thread Safety](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__tcp_stream.html#beast.ref.boost__beast__tcp_stream.thread_safety) often the initiation as well as the completion happen on the same (implicit) strand.

  If that's the case, then in your completion handler example, the `expires_never();` would be redundant.
- If the completion handler is *not* on the same strand, you want to actively avoid touching the expiry, because that would be a data race
- An alternative pattern is to set the expiry only once for a lengthier episode (e.g. an multi-message conversation between client/server). Obviously in this pattern, nobody would touch the expiry after initial setting. This seems pretty obvious, but I thought I'd mention it before someone casts this pattern in stone to never think about it again.

Always do what you need, prefer simple code. I think your basic understanding of the feature is right. (No wonder, [this documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/timeouts.html) is a piece of art).